# How does Ember map function expect parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I want to understand how the below code works in EmberJS?

```
Ember.$.map($this.get('myMap'), function(entitlements, id) {
    // What is entitlements & id here & what should be $this.get('myMap')?
})
```

is this conventional/standard JS syntax ?
Any examples would be great ?

Comment: (key, value) as http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Map.html

Comment: What do you have against [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/#method__)?

Answer (score 2):

`Ember.$` with lead you to jQuery, so you're using [jQuery's map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method.

Essentially what it does it call a function for each element in the array, allowing you to "map" that value to another and return it to be added to a new array. For instance:

If you have an array of javascript objects like `var names = [{ name: 'John', age: 12}, {name: 'Fred', age: 14}]` and you wanted to extract all names to a new array you could do:

```
 var names = [{ name: 'John', age: 12}, {name: 'Fred', age: 14}];
 var result = Ember.$.map(names, function(instance, index) {
   return instance.name
 })
 console.log(result) //Would print ['John', 'Fred'];
```

You could do all sort of things like return new objects to be added to the array.

Comment: Thx a lot. So the 2nd param to $.map would always be 'index' literally and cannot be any actual value from my array

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation the callback function receives an element in the array as the first argument and the index of that element in the second argument

Comment: Hmm...But on the jquery example page $.map( dimensions, function( value, key ) {}) returns the keys. Not sure why is that so ?

Comment: I think that's when you pass an object to the map function (instead of passing an array)